# calling the method of a class (queue) inside another class

Tags: c++

## node.h

-- used to create the hosts

```
 // host declaration

class Host : public Node {
    public:
        Host(uint32_t id, double rate, uint32_t queue_type, uint32_t host_type); // constructor
        Queue *queue; // queue to store the packets
        int host_type;
 };
```

## queue.h

--queue declaration, implemented using deque

```
class Queue {
    public:
        Queue(uint32_t id, double rate, uint32_t limit_bytes, int location); // default constructor
        virtual void enque(Packet *packet); // I want to call this function 

};
```

## main.cpp

-- Main program that creates the objects and tries to push  packets to the queue in the hosts

```
# include all the .h files

using namespace std;


int main()
{

Packet P1(20.4, 1, 0, 64); // creating a packet, not shows for simplicity
Host H1(0, 20.4,1, 0);     // creating my host  
H1.queue->enque(P1*); // This is where I get error 
                      // "invalid pointer".  I want to push the  
                      //packet P1 to the queue in the host, 
                      //I am not sure how to do it.  

return 0;

}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks,

Comment: Just write `H1.queue->enque(&P1);`. Also make sure that `queue` is initialized correctly.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but I get an error "expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token" in that line.

Comment: You need to use the address of operator.  `H1.Host::queue->enque(P1*);` => `H1.Host::queue->enque(&P1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `H1.queue->enque(&P1);`. This takes the *address* of the automatic variable `P1`.

But bear in mind that `&P1` is only valid for as long as `P1` is in scope. In production code, you probably want to use `new` to create a `Packet` instance and use that as the parameter to `enque`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried the following.                                                 `Packet *P1 = new Packet(20.4, 1, 0, 64);
H1.queue->enque(&P1); `  but still I have an issue in calling the enque function. `error: no matching function for call to ‘Queue::enque(Packet**)'`

Comment: @user2532296 You've mixed it up now. Either take address `&P1` or have a pointer variable `Packet*`.

Comment: Thanks @πάνταῥεῖ that made sense.